# Java SWT - Transparent background on canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, swt

Is it possible to fill a rectangle and an oval over a drawn image and having the oval being a "window" to the image behind it?

```
e.gc.drawImage(//...);
e.gc.setBackground(//black);
e.gc.fillRectangle(//over the image);
e.gc.setBackground(//SWT.TRANSPARENT?);
e.gc.fillOval(somewhere on the canvas);
```

this snippet obviously isn't working for me, but can this even be achieved with SWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it,

what I did was create a new shell with the SWT.NO_TRIM property (it's parent is the canvas/costume widget) and use `setRegion()` on it.

The trick was the region itself, it has a  `subtract()`  method, 
so I found a method that produces a polygon and I subtracted it from the region.

Than I set it and voilà.
I had to add resize and move listeners so it would look "natural" (i.e, part of the canvas and not a new shell).

It works really well actually.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fillOval()` and `fillRectangle()`, use `drawOval()` and `drawRectangle()` to draw the outline instead of filling the area.

Here's the [JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/GC.html):

> **Draws the outline** of an oval, using the foreground color, within the specified rectangular area.

Whereas `fillOval()` does:

> **Fills the interior** of an oval, within the specified rectangular area, with the receiver's background color.

Comment: Yes I'm aware to these options, I should have mentioned that the rectangle has to cover the image, while the oval needs to be transparent.

Comment: @omm118 Well, then use `fillRectangle()` and `drawOval()`

Comment: @omm118 Or do you want the oval to "remove" parts of the rectangle?

Comment: If I'll use    fillRectangle  and than    drawOval the oval's background would be the rectangle, and if I'll use    drawOval and than    fillRectangle the rectangle would just cover the oval too.

Comment: @omm118 Don't know how to do that. You may need to draw a polygon yourself